# MONO - Method 'EventSource.WriteEvent' not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I have a problem with my ASP.NET MVC app with Mono. I'm creating a simple app in Visual Studio. The app works on windows server but not on Mono. I get this error:

```
System.MissingMethodException Method 'EventSource.WriteEvent' not found.
```

Mono Version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b Wed Mar 16 13:19:08 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            sgen
```

Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all overloads of `EventSource.WriteEvent` are implemented in Mono. You either need to change your code to use only those implemented or wait for Cycle 7 release. I think it will be called Mono 4.4, but you have 4.2, so you'll have to upgrade.

Comment: Just found this related to your problem: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27337

Comment: Problem is that I am not using that method in entire project :(

Comment: Maybe you're using a library which uses it?

Comment: @JaSHin Looking at your screenshot your problem starts in constructor of: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.cs, which calls `Log` method in https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/Implementation/WebEventSource.cs, which in fact does use `Diagnostics.Tracing` from either `System` or `Microsoft` namespace, depending on .NET version.

Comment: Mono 4.4 Beta fixed my problem.

Comment: @JaSHin Glad that my answer helped you. Would you mind accepting it?